# Underlying error code -17221, what does that mean?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, tvos

Suddenly when streaming FPS HLS content on an AppleTV I get an `AVFoundation` error `-11800` with an underlying error where the domain is `NSOSStatusErrorDomain` and the error code is `-17221`

I'm trying to figure out what the error code `-17221` is but I can't find it anywhere. Tried [OSStatus.com](http://osstatus.com) and searching all the header files but no luck.

Now, if I restart the AppleTV, everything is back to normal. The challenge is that I need to be able to pinpoint why this is happening in order to give users better feedback.

Can anyone tell me why `-17221` is happening and possibly where it is defined?

This is the error output in the Xcode console, I had to remove the NSURL as it points to a URL I cannot expose.

> Mar  6 10:47:00 4k-team App(AVKit)[168] : -[AVNowPlayingPlaybackControlsViewController _updateLoadingAndErrorIndicators] The player item has failed. error = Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 “The operation could not be completed” UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c505fb90 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17221 “(null)“}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-17221), NSURL=https://fileToStream.m3u8, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed

Comment: I had a lot of this error on production according to error logs. I cannot figure out how to reproduce this error either.

Comment: @mr2k have you ever found an explanation for that? Would be interesting, because I observe these errors occasionally.